Catching stack-trace in catchAsync function
So I have my server.js like this
//server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express()

// Error Handler Controller
const globalErrorHandler = require('./controllers/error.controller');

// Import routes
const emailsRoutes = require('./routes/emails.routes')
const notificationsRoutes = require('./routes/notifications.routes')
const reportsRoutes = require('./routes/reports.routes')
const systemRoutes = require('./routes/system.routes')
const siteRoutes = require('./routes/sites.routes')
const accessRoutes = require('./routes/access.routes')
// etc ...

app.use('/v1/emails' ,emailsRoutes)
app.use('/v1/notifications',  notificationsRoutes)
app.use('/v1/reports',  reportsRoutes)
app.use('/v1/system',  systemRoutes)
app.use('/v1/sites',  siteRoutes)
app.use('/v1/access',  accessRoutes)

// Add this AFTER all your routes
app.use(globalErrorHandler);

The structure of the routes files is the next
const emailsRouter = require("express").Router();
const { userValidation } = require("../middleware/Permissions");
const { 
  getEmailGroupsForConfig,
  postEmailGroupsForConfig,
  updateEmailGroupsForConfig
} = require("../controllers/email.controller");

emailsRouter.use(userValidation());

emailsRouter.get("/groups", getEmailGroupsForConfig);
emailsRouter.post("/groups", postEmailGroupsForConfig);
emailsRouter.put("/groups", updateEmailGroupsForConfig);

module.exports = emailsRouter;

My controller files are as follows, each function is exported and independent of all the others
'use strict'
const catchAsync = require("../utils/catchAsync");
const { vmsfull_dbc, replica_dbc } = require("../database_connection");
const AppError = require("../utils/appError");

exports.getEmailGroupsForConfig = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user.checkUserPermission('write-email-groups')) {
    return next( new AppError("Unauthorized", 403));
  }
  let sql_query = 'SELECT * from vms_metadata."email_groups" ORDER BY group_name ASC';

  const emailGroupe = await vmsfull_dbc.query(sql_query);

  return res.status(200).send(emailGroupe.rows);
});

Finally, my catch async is the following and it is where I have my question
module.exports = fn => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).catch(err => {
      // Preservar el stack trace original
      const newError = new Error(err.message);
      newError.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
      newError.status = err.status || 'error';
      newError.stack = err.stack; // Preservar el stack trace original

      console.error(newError); // Imprimir el error
      console.trace(error); // Imprimir el stack trace completo

      next(newError);
    });
  };
};

I want to be able to know which middleware or which endpoint had the error, I do detect the error, however when printing console.trace(error);
It only appears from my catchAsync.js file
Trace: [Error]
    at C:\My\Path\Directory\server\src\utils\catchAsync.js:22:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


Uh, why are you creating a newError at all?!

console.trace will always print the trace of the call to console.trace itself (with a preceding message). You'll want to print error.stack instead.

Hello, I solved the problem, apparently it was something related to the pg library, I just had to update to the most recent version and this worked as I expected.
